# desktop launcher is not successfully setting environment

Tags: bash, matlab

I created a MATLAB desktop launcher. It executes `matlab -desktop` fine, but my configuration requires that some environment variables are set first. When I open a terminal, these variables are set by `/etc/bash.bashrc`, which sources a script for setting up the work environment.

I created a script to try to work around this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/environment/setup/script.sh
matlab -desktop
```

I set my launcher to execute this script. It launches MATLAB successfully, but the variables are still not set correctly. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to export variables into the script's environment from an external script, then you need to source the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
. /path/to/environment/setup/script.sh
matlab -desktop
```